# Sentence structure when the verb and its preposition are separated by a long clause

Tags: sentence-structure, prepositional-phrases

For example:

> I have notified my colleague, who has been working on this field for
>   many years, of the issue.

The way it sounds to me is; as the clause (`"who has been..."`) gets longer, it gets more difficult to follow the prepositional clause (`"of the issue"`). What is a better way to write this sentence?

Comment: It is a [non-defining relative clause][1], I think. Although it is very clear, you can convey the same information in several ways. "I notified my friend. He had worked on this filed for many years." [1]: http://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/quick-grammar/relative-clauses-non-defining-relative-clauses

Comment: You could split your sentences. "I have notified my colleague of this issue. Be assured that he has been working in this field for many years and is very experienced."

Comment: Thank you both. So I think the sentece is ok and there isn't much room for improvement except by splitting it.

Answer (score 1):

The sentence is OK.

As @Leo suggested in the comments:

> You could split your sentences. **"I have notified my colleague of this issue. Be assured that he has been working in this field for many years and is very experienced."**